# JS DOM append child does not work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a simple function that gets some list of elements (in this case I pass some `<li>` elements) and append them in random order to some parent node (`<ul>`). To do this I wrote something like that:

```
console.log(tmpList);
var maxIndex = tmpList.length;
while(tmpList.length > 0) {
    var curIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxIndex);
    if(tmpList[curIndex] && tmpList[curIndex].nodeType===1) {
        var elem = tmpList.splice(curIndex, 1);
        console.log(elem);
        parent.appendChild(elem);
    }
}
```

As you can see I do check if the randomly chosed index actually still exists in the `tmpList` and if it's actually html element. However though when I run this code I get:

```
[li, li, li, li]
[li]
NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null.
```

What do I do wrong?

ps. Please don't give me advices like "use jquery" or "just concatenate it using innerHTML" because there are reasons I cannot use them.

[edit] `parent` element is defined a few lines earlier so it's not the case.

**UPDATE**

I made some changes according to one answer so the code looks as follow:

```
while(tmpList.length > 0) {
    var curIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * tmpList.length);
    var elem = tmpList.splice(curIndex, 1);
    console.log(elem);
    if(elem instanceof HTMLElement) {
        //console.log(curIndex);

        console.log(elem);
        parent.appendChild(elem);
    }
}
return true;
```

Now it looks a little bit better but still works strange. Now the console output is:

```
[li, li, li, li]
[li]
[li]
[li]
[li]
```

So it has li elements but does not treat them as HTMLNode... :o (the same result was when I used `elem !== null && elem !== undefined && elem.nodeType === 1`)

Comment: How about you add something like `if (typeof elem !== null) parent.appendChild(elem);` into your loop at the end?

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle that throws the same error you're seeing in console? Would be much easier to help then.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UR3ZQ/ <-- however I don't see any console with errors there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `maxIndex` before `while` and in `while` you change your array, so I advice you to change:

```
var curIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxIndex);
```

to (this will ensure that curIndex will be always less than tmpList.lenght)

```
var curIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * tmpList.length);
```

then splice your array and validate your element: (for better validation you should check if your `elem` is html element)

```
while(tmpList.length > 0) {
    var curIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * tmpList.length);
    if (curIndex < tmpList.lenght){
        var elem = tmpList.splice(curIndex, 1);
        // array.splice returns array of removed from array elements, so you need work with first element in that array.

        if (elem[0] instanceof HTMLElement && elem[0].nodeType === 1){
            //Add to parent:
            parent.appendChild(elem[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about it but if I remove tmpList[1], then tmpList.length will have value 3 (in this case) and Math.random() *tmpList.length will never generate value 3 so it will never remove tmpList[3]... Nevermind, I checked it.

Comment: lets say `arr` has 3 items, so `arr.lenght` is 3, but `arr[3]` will return undefined or null, because arrays are zero-based, it means `arr[0]` is first item, `arr[1]` is second, `arr[2]` is third item. Math.random() maximum value at first circle is 2 (index of third item)

Comment: I know this much. Just though that JS doesn't change indexes when removing some element in the middle (I mean if I have indexes 0,1,2 and remove it could have 0,2 with null in place of 1)

Comment: run this code: `var arr = ['a','b','c'];`, then check values with their indexes: `arr.forEach(function(e,i){ console.log(i,e)});`, then splice one element: `console.log(arr.splice(1,1)); //Returns 'b'`, then check again indexes and values: `arr.forEach(function(e,i){ console.log(i,e)});`. You will notice that `'c'` had index 2 before item was removed, after that `'c'` has index 1.

Comment: You helped me with array indexing (and I gave you +1) but the answer did not solve the problem (I've found and described a problem below). Sorry, this is nothing personal, it's just that someone might get into such problem in the future should be able to recognize the proper answer.

Comment: @Moby04 take a look at my edited answer (edited before my previous comment). array.splice returns not element, but new array of removed elements. if u remove from array `[A,B,C,D]` `B` and `C`, then splice will return `[B,C]`, if you remove `B`, then splice will return `[B]` (array of single element), so you need to validate first object from returned array and push also first object from returned array. Look at my answer. It's a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have element named `parent`

Comment: Actually parent is an element passed as a function param earlier. I just pasted the part that goes down. Also, please notice that the browser does not report that parent is null (and it has appendChild method)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem. Trick is that elem holds list containing one matching element. THe solution is to use `elem[0]`.

Comment: It's too easy to ignore the [] in the console. Can't tell you how many times I've been bit by this type of thing and how many times I tell myself it will never happen again.

Comment: Yup, most trivial bugs are the worst ones... :) http://www.smashingapps.com/2010/12/18/what-its-like-to-be-a-programmer.html